# How to add class row in jQuery if bootstrap column reach 12?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this jquery code which will append image inside a div container. I just want to add div class row if the column reach 12.

Can anyone give me an idea. Thankyou in advance.

```
for (var i = 0, j = result.images.length; i < j; i++){
    $("#imageContent").append("<div class='col-md-3'><img src='storage/uploaded/" + result.images[i].name + "' class='img-responsive img-thumbnail'></div>");
}
```

here my div

```
<div class="container" id="imageContent" style="display: block;">

</div>
```

here is my current output.

```
<div class="container" id="imageContent" style="display: block;">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="storage/uploaded/attl1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="storage/uploaded/attl2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="storage/uploaded/May 11, 2017.png" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="storage/uploaded/8.png" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="storage/uploaded/logo.png" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="storage/uploaded/a2la_logo.png" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="storage/uploaded/attl1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
</div>
```

but I want to add Div class row if column reaches 12
expected output

```
<div class="container" id="imageContent" style="display: block;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="storage/uploaded/attl1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="storage/uploaded/attl2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="storage/uploaded/May 11, 2017.png" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="storage/uploaded/8.png" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="storage/uploaded/logo.png" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="storage/uploaded/a2la_logo.png" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="storage/uploaded/attl1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this

```
for (var i = 0, j = result.images.length; i < j; i++){

    if(i==0 || i%4 == 0)
    {
        var appendEl = $("<div class='row'></div>").appendTo("#imageContent");
    }
    $("<div class='col-md-3'><img src='storage/uploaded/" + result.images[i].name  + "' class='img-responsive img-thumbnail'></div>").appendTo(appendEl);
}
```

Check the js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9Lrg2ecq/

Updated:  Please check the screen shot https://ibb.co/fzcR6Q

Comment: Please check the snapshot & i added `i` instead of `result.images[i].name` & length was hardcoded to create the sample. Check now

Comment: Yea it's working :) Thankyou so much sir. exactly what I'm looking :)

Comment: @GeninaAnneGabuten Glad i could help

Comment: btw what's the difference of $("#imageContent").append("<div class='row'></div>") to your code?

Comment: `appendTo` returns me the newly element instead of  `#imageContent`(if i used the `append` method)

Comment: Nice answer. `0 % 4` equals to 0, so basically you don't need to check whether `i == 0` since `i % 4 == 0` covers this as well.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use another loop, wrapping your current loop, making a "paginator-like" behavior. The first loop will count how many rows you'll need (number of images divided by 4 because u have 4 columns in each row), and the inner loop will iterate 4 times to populate that row.

```
for (index = 0 ; index < images.length / 4 ; index++) {
    var row = document.createElement('div');
    row.className="row";
    for (j = index * 4 ; j < (index * 4) + 4 ; j++) {
        var col = document.createElement('div');
        $(col).addClass("col-md-4");
        $(col).html('<img src="' + images[j] + '"/>');
        $(row).append(col);
    }
    $('body').append(row);
}
```

Comment: How can I apply this to my current loop sir? sorry I was new in jquery

Comment: I try by 

for (index = 0 ; index < result.images.length / 4 ; index++) {
         $('#imageContent').html('<div class="row"></div>');
         for (j = index * 4 ; j < (index * 4) + 4 ; j++) {
             $("#imageContent").append("<div class='col-md-3'><img src='storage/uploaded/" + result.images[index].name + "' class='img-responsive img-thumbnail'></div>"); 
         } 

     }

but not putting the images inside the row.

Comment: When creating a new `row`, you'll need to give it a variable and then add the columns to that variable. What you did was just creating rows and the images outside the rows. Let me edit my answer to be more explicit...

Answer (score 0):

You should create a function which count how many `col-md-3` class there are in the `last-child` of the last row on your container.

Example: `$('.container .row:last-child .col-md-4').length;`

If there are more than 4 `col-md-3`, create your `.row` element and recall this function
Else, add `$("#imageContent").append("<div class='col-md-3'>...");`on the last row child :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this with wrapAll() function of jQuery. http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/

I wasn't able to test this but your code should be like this:

```
for (var i = 0, j = result.images.length; i < j; i++) {
            if (i % 4 == 0) {
                $("#imageContent").append("<div class='col-md-3'><img src='storage/uploaded/" + result.images[i].name + "' class='img-responsive img-thumbnail'></div>");
                $(".col-md-3").wrapAll("<div class='row' />");
            }

            else {
                $("#imageContent").append("<div class='col-md-3'><img src='storage/uploaded/" + result.images[i].name + "' class='img-responsive img-thumbnail'></div>");
            }
        }
```

Comment: I tried your code sir it created row and inside the 1st row there's another row with 5images

Answer (score 0):

try this, may be this will help you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">

  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <div  id="new_row">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="background-color:yellow;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="background-color:green;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div> 
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="background-color:orange;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div> 
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="background-color:red;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div> 
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() { 

for (var i = 0, j = 10; i < j; i++){

if(i==0 || i%4 == 0)
{
   var appendEl = $("<div class='row'></div>").appendTo("#new_row");
}
    $("</div><div class='col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3'><img src='storage/uploaded/" + i + "' class='img-responsive img-thumbnail'></div>").appendTo(appendEl);
}
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thankyou sir you have same answer like agam and it's correct also.

Comment: Yeah, it okay, almost same answer, But with clear example

Answer (score 0):

```
       <div class="row">
            <?php   $counter =0;
                    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
                    $args = array(
                      'posts_per_page' => 4,
                      'paged' => $paged
                    );
                    $custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                       while($custom_query->have_posts()) :
                          $custom_query->the_post();
            ?>
            <?php
                    if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
                        $post_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large');
                        }
            ?>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                <div class="latest-news">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $post_image[0];?>" /></a>
                    <h4><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></h4>
                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                    <h5>
                        <?php $content= get_the_content(); 
                              echo $contentCut = substr($content, 0, 100).'...';
                        ?>
                    </h5>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">By
                                <span><?php echo get_the_author(); ?></span> |</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">comment
                                <span><?php echo get_comments_number(); ?></span> |</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Likes
                                <span><?php if (function_exists('wp_ulike_get_post_likes')){

                                            $count= wp_ulike_get_post_likes(get_the_ID());
                                            if($count > 0)
                                            {
                                              echo $count;
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                               echo '0';
                                            }
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php 
                  $counter++;
                  if($counter%3==0) 
                  echo '</div><div class="row">';
                  endwhile; 
            ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, your answer might be correct, but you must provide some explanation about it to show why it's correct